# pyproj not working on ipython (but works on CLI)

Tags: python, powershell, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I am having trouble executing `pyproj` while using IPython Notebook but not when using Python in powershell.

IPython throws up the following error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-384a2e8bfd70> in <module>()
----> 1 inproj = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:3857')

C:\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\pyproj\__init__.pyc in __new__(self, projparams, preserve_units, **kwargs)
    345                 else:
    346                     kvpairs.append(kvpair+' ')
--> 347             projstring = ''.join(kvpairs)
    348         # look for EPSG, replace with epsg (EPSG only works
    349         # on case-insensitive filesystems).

_proj.pyx in _proj.Proj.__cinit__ (_proj.c:1190)()

RuntimeError: Invalid argument
```

The issue is similar to the one pointed out here https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj/issues/17 but I don't understand how the code runs well on the command line. Do you know how I can get `pyproj` to work? I am using windows (64 bit), conda version: 3.18.6 and python version: 2.7.10.

If it helps, the output to `pyproj.pyproj_datadir` on ipython notebook is `'C:\x07root\\stage\\Library\\share\\proj'` whereas it it is `'C:\\Anaconda64\\lib\\site-packages\\pyproj\\data'` on the command prompt.

Thank you!

The working example I used is from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78838/how-to-convert-projected-coordinates-to-lat-lon-using-python/78944#78944

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

inProj = Proj(init='epsg:3857')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
x1,y1 = -11705274.6374,4826473.6922
x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
print x2,y2
```

Comment: This was a [bug](https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj/issues/17), run `conda update pyproj` and get pyproj>=1.9.5 to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error running Python 2.7.11 in Windows 10 (64 bit) under miniconda. My pyproj version was 1.9.4 (as determined by running `conda list`). Several solutions were suggested on the [link](https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj/issues/17) you mentioned:

1. Downgrade pyproj to v1.9.3 from the [JimInCO](https://anaconda.org/JimInCO/pyproj) channel on anaconda.org. This didn't work for my environment - I couldn't find any suitable v1.9.3 packages. It looks like there may be some Python 3 offerings there.
2. Define an environment variable called `PROJ_DIR` that points pyproj to the correct location for its projection files. You'd have to identify the location of the epsg file first.
3. **This is the solution that worked for me**. Grab a whl file from [Christoph Gohlke's site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyproj) an install using `pip install the_file.whl`. Using this method, I obtained pyproj v1.9.5, which works fine.